# How can I call a non-static function from an abstract class in PHP 8?

Tags: php, abstract-class, static-methods, php-8

I want to update our current project that runs on PHP 7.2 but I got an issue that I cant resolve easily.

```
public function getCategories($type){...}

//In another file that dosent implements Category
$categories = Category::getCategories('xxx');
```

The issue I have is, that in PHP 8 you cant call non-static functions anymore staticly, but I also can't rewrite it to `$categories = (new Category)->getCategories('xxx');` because its an abstract class.

As a temporary solution, I've considered converting getCategories into a static method. However, I'm concerned about potential side effects this change might have on the project.

Does anyone have a suggestion for handling this situation in PHP 8? Ideally, I'm looking for a solution that avoids modifying the method's static/non-static status while still complying with PHP 8's stricter standards.

Comment: Extend your abstract class and use that one instead

Comment: If the Method is not referencing him self in any way, which seem to be the case, to make method static is the correct way.

Comment: You are calling the method in a static way, so it should be declared static, that's all.

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of any side effect you aren't already hitting in PHP/7. The method is already being called statically, so if it happens to try to access a class instance, it would be already crashing:

```
abstract class Category
{
    public $foo = [1, 2, 3];

    public function getCategories($type)
    {
        return $this->foo;
    }
}

class ChildCategory extends Category
{
}

// This works fine
$categories = (new ChildCategory())->getCategories('xxx');
var_dump($categories);

// Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context
$categories = Category::getCategories('xxx');
var_dump($categories);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/eMj68#v7.0.33)

If it isn't crashing, that proves it's static at its core, so you can just make it official:

```
abstract class Category
{
    public static function getCategories($type)
    {
        return [1, 2, 3];
    }
}

class ChildCategory extends Category
{
}

$categories = (new ChildCategory())->getCategories('xxx');
var_dump($categories);

$categories = Category::getCategories('xxx');
var_dump($categories);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/LJ2Pl)

Note that is perfectly fine to invoke a static method from a class instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can call a non-static function from an abstract class in PHP 8 using [anonymous classes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.anonymous.php) extending the abstract class.

```
<?php
 
class Category {
    public function getCategories($type){
        $array = [
            'xxx' => 'foo',
            'yyy' => 'bar'
        ];
 
        return ($array[$type] ?? 'foo bar');
    }
}
 
echo (new class() extends Category {})->getCategories('xxx');
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/JhEa71)